# Automapper same source class, different inputs. Same output. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to merge two different inputs into one output using AutoMapper.

```
List<MerchantListViewModel> merchants = new List<MerchantListViewModel>();

var regularMerchants = Mapper.Map<List<Discount>, List<MerchantListViewModel>>(result.RegularDiscounts);
var specialMerchants = Mapper.Map<List<Discount>, List<MerchantListViewModel>>(result.OurSpecialDiscounts);

merchants.AddRange(regularMerchants);
merchants.AddRange(specialMerchants);

return merchants;


public class MerchantListViewModel 
{
   ...
   public bool IsSpecialDiscount { get; set; }
}
```

I want to set a flag on MerchantListViewModel to IsSpecialDiscount to be true when the second map occurs. The first map would set it to false or not set it. Is there a way to do it?
I am mapping Legacy code into new ViewModels which is where this requirement is coming from. I don't have an option to change the legacy code from the two lists that I am given.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be you can add this line before you call AddRange function. specialMerchants.ForEach(li=>ii.IsSpecialDiscount =true). Or are you looking for automapper based solution only?

Comment: that's a good point, didn't think about it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.AfterMap()` action per https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions  I'm not sure the values of your objects, so you may or may not be able to do it in your configuration. Performing the action during mapping would be about equivalent to using the LINQ `.ForEach()` as noted in the comments. You may also have the option of rolling your own `ValueResolver` class like https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers